# IRSSI notifier - by pulling method

Tags: perl, notifications, irssi

Is there an option in irssi to **get state about new unread private and public messages** by external application.

If there is such option, i could periodically read that info from my bash script and do what i want with that, on any local or remote computer, when i want.

notify.pl (irssi-libnotify) is great if you want to send notify to ONE X-server. It works for remote X-Server too. But impossible for multiple notify-clients, because it is EVENT-driven, when new message arrive, script must do something and information disappears (that is i think called PUSH strategy).

for implementing PULLing (like mail pop or imap notifiers does for example), only thing that is needed is new-mesages-status... if it is available to external app, or at least to inside perl scripts (in documentation i only saw events - not status)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script activity_file.pl from https://scripts.irssi.org/
It maintains a csv file named *activity_file* in ~/.irssi/ which columns are : the ID of the window, the activity code, the name of the user/channel, and the server.

All you have to do then is to have a script periodically checking the activity file and launch whatever action you like upon change.